# Text stuck next to the navbar unless I do many line breaks

Tags: html, css

When I try put text after my navbar, it is stuck on the same line. Currently trying to do the freecodecamp responsive web design certification, so a bit of a noob, and I appreciate that my code might be a little messy. Still new to this and I'm not sure how some code works, like the positioning of my navbar as a block which I feel like might be causing an issue. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```css
html { 
  background: url("https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/patterns/ep_naturalwhite.png");
}
.image-center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 20%;
  
}
#header-img {
  border-radius: 15%;
  object-fit: cover;
  height:200px;
}

.nav-link {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  background: rgb(47, 204, 118);
  
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: block;
}
 .nav-link:hover {
  color: rgb(47, 204, 118);
  background: white;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.25rem;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #1e1e24;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #6649b8;
}
.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width:40%;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-justify: center;
}

h3 {
  font-family: calibri;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <img src="https://www.freelogodesign.org/file/app/client/thumb/57b26682-f831-4123-9003-93366bef2465_200x200.png?1601028498829" class="image-center" id="header-img">
  
  <nav id="nav-bar" class="center topnav">
    <a href="#about" class="nav-link" id="nav-link1">About us</a>
    <a href="#product" class="nav-link" id="nav-link2">The Product</a>
    <a href="#timeline" class="nav-link" id="nav-link3">Our Progress & Timeline</a>
    <a href="#contact" class="nav-link" id="nav-link4">Contact Us</a>
  </nav>
  </header>

  <br><br><br>
   <h3>hi</h3>
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @abney317 with regards to using display Flex on the `.center` class, given the fact that the `nav` element is the parent container. Additionally, I’d like to point out a few suggestions to improve your code.

1. The HTML is missing some tags that are very important for a proper
   DOM structure, such as `body`and the `head`.
2. The references (links) to your script and your CSS stylesheet should be inside the `head` tag.
3. Remember that CSS means Cascading Style Sheet, therefore the order
   of the style rules matter. You should style your HTML document in
   descending order from top to bottom.
4. After the header, it's always a good practice to wrap your next
   block of content inside a container tag: `div`, `section`,
   `article`, `aside`.

I made some modifications to your code, for illustration purposes.

Keep up the good work and never stop learning!

```
//HTML 

<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
 
  <header id="header">
      <img src="https://www.freelogodesign.org/file/app/client/thumb/57b26682-f831-4123-9003-93366bef2465_200x200.png?1601028498829" class="image-center" id="header-img">
 
      <nav id="nav-bar" class="center topnav">
        <a href="#about" class="nav-link" id="nav-link1">About us</a>
        <a href="#product" class="nav-link" id="nav-link2">The Product</a>
        <a href="#timeline" class="nav-link" id="nav-link3">Our Progress & Timeline</a>
        <a href="#contact" class="nav-link" id="nav-link4">Contact Us</a>
      </nav>

  </header>

  <div>
    <h3>hi</h3>
  </div>
   
</body>
</html>

//CSS

html {
  background: url("https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/patterns/ep_naturalwhite.png");
}

body {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-justify: center;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.25rem;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #1e1e24;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #6649b8;
}

h3 {
  font-family: calibri;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.image-center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 20%;
 
}

#header-img {
  border-radius: 15%;
  object-fit: cover;
  height:200px;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  background: rgb(47, 204, 118);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width:40%;
}

.topnav a {
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.nav-link {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
 .nav-link:hover {
  color: rgb(47, 204, 118);
  background: white;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are using float.

there are three soluftion for it:

1. Use overflow auto in nav

> .center {
> display: block;
> margin-left: auto;
> margin-right: auto;
> width:40%;
> overflow: auto;
> }

2. Use display flex
   if it meet your requirement, you can change display of nav to flex

> .center {
> display: flex;
> margin-left: auto;
> margin-right: auto;
> width:40%;
> }

3. Add a blank div with clear between header and your text

```
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `float: left` and `width: 40%` was causing the problems you were seeing.

You can use change your `.center` class to make use of `display: flex` instead.

```css
html {
  background: url("https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/patterns/ep_naturalwhite.png");
}

.image-center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 20%;
}

#header-img {
  border-radius: 15%;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 200px;
}

.nav-link {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  background: rgb(47, 204, 118);
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: block;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: rgb(47, 204, 118);
  background: white;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.25rem;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #1e1e24;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #6649b8;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.topnav a {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-justify: center;
}

h3 {
  font-family: calibri;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <img src="https://www.freelogodesign.org/file/app/client/thumb/57b26682-f831-4123-9003-93366bef2465_200x200.png?1601028498829" class="image-center" id="header-img">

  <nav id="nav-bar" class="center topnav">
    <a href="#about" class="nav-link" id="nav-link1">About us</a>
    <a href="#product" class="nav-link" id="nav-link2">The Product</a>
    <a href="#timeline" class="nav-link" id="nav-link3">Our Progress & Timeline</a>
    <a href="#contact" class="nav-link" id="nav-link4">Contact Us</a>
  </nav>
</header>


<h3>hi</h3>
```